# compute $P(XY\leq 3)$, $P(X+Y>2)$ and $P(X/Y>1)$

Tags: probability

> The joint probability mass function of $X$ and $Y$ is given by
>
> $p(1,1)=\frac{1}{8}$   $p(2,1)=\frac{1}{8}$
>
> $p(1,2)=\frac{1}{4}$     $p(2,2)=\frac{1}{2}$
>
> compute $P(XY\leq 3)$, $P(X+Y>2)$ and $P(X/Y>1)$

My attempt:

$P(XY\leq 3)=P(1,1)+P(1,2)+P(2,1)=\frac{1}{2}$

$P(X+Y>2)=P(1,2)=P(2,1)+P(2,2)=\frac{7}{8}$

But what about $P(X/Y>1)$? Is it $\frac{P(X=i,Y=2)}{P(y>1)}$ ?
where $u=1,2$

Comment: Sorry for colliding with your edits.  I've rollbacked to yours.

Comment: what are the events such that $X/Y>1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your attempts are right for

$P(XY\leq 3)=P(1,1)+P(1,2)+P(2,1)=\frac{1}{2} $ and $P(X+Y>2)=P(1,2)=P(2,1)+P(2,2)=\frac{7}{8}$

To calculate $P(X/Y>1)$, think about what combination of X and Y give you the desired result from the distribution. As you see only X = 2, Y=1 satisfies the required condition. So

$$P(X/Y>1) = P(2,1) = \frac 1 4$$